# Autowire Spring Boot classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some code that is trying to Autowire a Bean that contains the Spring Boot class `RestTemplate`.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean{

    @Autowired
    RequestPublicKey requestPublicKey;

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            System.out.println(requestPublicKey.getPublicKey());
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        }
}
```

My initial code for the class `RequestPublicKey` looks like this:

```
@Component
public class RequestPublicKey {

    public String getPublicKey(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String publicCreds = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/get-public-key?kid=bf3b7429-261e-48c5-8409-79e1c9f203de", String.class);
        return publicCreds;
    }
}
```

When I try to Autowire `RequestPublicKey` it returns `null`. I think that is due to that I instantiate `RestTemplate` with `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()`. To get around that issue I tried to Autowire `RestTemplate` like this

```
@Component
public class RequestPublicKey {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String getPublicKey(){
        String publicCreds = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/get-public-key?kid=bf3b7429-261e-48c5-8409-79e1c9f203de", String.class);
        return publicCreds;
    }
}
```

But then I get the `Could not autowire. No beans of type RestTemplate found`.

Is it possible to Autowire Spring Boot classes? Or should I just instantiate `RequestPublicKey` like `RequestPublicKey requestPublicKey = new RequestPublicKey()`?

Comment: have you defined `RestTemplate` bean in config? I suspect you have not

Comment: @Mr.Arjun. No haven't defined it in config. Do you have an example of what that would look like? Sorry I've just started learning Spring Boot and Spring.

Comment: could you just edit question and add config code there

Comment: there is no need to make `RestTemplate` a spring bean. But you are saying if you autowire `RequestPublicKey` anywhere it is null. This should not be the case. can you show the class where `RequestPublicKey` is autowired.

Comment: Try to add a constructor on RequestPublicKey

Comment: @Patrick I try to Autowire `RequestPublicKey` in `public class JWTAuthenticationFilter` (the first class in the question) that extends `GenericFilterBean`. I now realised that this seems to be where I have my problem since I'm not able to Autowire `RequestPublicKey` from the class `JWTAuthenticationFilter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in the comments, Spring does not provide a RestTemplate for you automatically. So you either have to set up it yourself, like e.g.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Or you use the RestTemplateBuilder instead which is provided by Spring (boot), so can let Spring inject that to your code.

```
@Component
public class RequestPublicKey {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public RequestPublicKey(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
         this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
    ...
```

This has some benefits like Spring setting up HttpMessageConverters for your, and you may use the RestTemplateCustomizer. See more information on that in the [Spring Boot Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-restclient.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. I realised now that my problem is earlier when I try to Autowire `RequestPublicKey` from `JWTAuthenticationFilter`. I tried running `RestTemplate` directly in `JWTAuthenticationFilter` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. I had two issues with Autowiring. First issue was that some extra setup is needed to Autowire from a `GenericFilterBean`. I found the a way to setup it up [here (link to SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494398/unable-to-autowire-the-service-inside-my-authentication-filter-in-spring) and [here (link to SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537388/use-autowired-with-a-filter-configured-in-springboot). The second issue was how to Autowire the `RestTemplate`. I went with [Ralf's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43362337/2420986). Thanks for all the help.